# How do I quote a person with a nickname?

Tags: quotations, nicknames

How would I set up the quotations for this sentence:

"The current governor of California is Edmund G. "Jerry" Brown, a Democrat who was inaugurated January 3, 2011" (governors.library.ca.gov).

Do I replace the nickname quotations with apostrophes or keep it as is?

Comment: If the answers given answer your question adequately, you should mark one of them as the correct answer; otherwise, please edit your question to indicate _why_ the answers given do not adequately answer it.

Answer (score 3):

According to several references, you might want to use single quotes instead of double ones if they are used inside a quoted portion of text.

[Grammarbook.com](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/quotes.asp):

> Use single quotation marks for quotations within quotations.
>
> **Example:** He said, "Dan cried, 'Do not treat me that way.' "
>
> Note that the period goes inside both the single and double quotation marks.

[Grammarly.com](http://www.grammarly.com/handbook/punctuation/quotation-marks/6/quotations-within-a-quotation/):

> If you are using double quotation marks for the “outside quote”, then use single quotation marks for the “inside quote”; if you’re using single quotes on the outside, use doubles on the inside.
>
> “I see no need,” my mother drawled, “for ‘contemplation’, as you put it. Get up off the couch and start doing your homework.”
>
> Annie said, ‘I’ve gone through this whole essay, and I can’t find what your professor means by “that other issue”’.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a good [reference on " (double) vs ' (single) quote marks](http://www.scribendi.com/advice/when_to_use_double_or_single_quotation_marks.en.html)

"Re-quoting" the nickname ("Jerry") inside a double-quotation. In this case, use your single quotes.